# Svg image is not displayed on PDF file

Tags: java, svg, html-to-pdf, openhtmltopdf

I'm using 0.0.1-RC14 openhtmltopdf version for generating PDF files from html. I have svg image on my html template. This is a snippet of my code:

```
PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
builder.defaultTextDirection(BaseRendererBuilder.TextDirection.LTR); 
builder.useSVGDrawer(new BatikSVGDrawer()); builder.useMathMLDrawer(new 
MathMLDrawer()); builder.addDOMMutator(LaTeXDOMMutator.INSTANCE); 
builder.useDefaultPageSize(210, 297, BaseRendererBuilder.PageSizeUnits.MM); 
builder.withHtmlContent(html, "");
builder.toStream(os); 
builder.run();
```

What I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue after upgrading openhtmltopdf library to the latest version: **0.0.1-RC15** and adding namespace attribute to the `svg` element: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` :

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ...> ... </svg>"`

For detailed information refer to https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/wiki/Plugins:-SVG-Images or https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/issues/258#issuecomment-410269938

Comment: I am using version 1.0.4 of openhtmltopdf , and am facing the same problem. svg image is not displaying in the pdf. Any clue ??

Answer (score 0):

Im using openhtmlpdf-svg-support 1.0.7 version, Im not able to add SVG in PDF.

My code is something like this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
            <image x="20" y="20" width="300" height="80" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Test-Logo.svg"/>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

```java
final PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();

builder.withHtmlContent(content, null);
builder.useSVGDrawer(new BatikSVGDrawer());

try {
    builder.toStream(
            new FileOutputStream("C:\\Codebase\\spring\\pdf\\src\\main\\java\\pdfbox\\FinalSVG.pdf"));
    builder.run();
} catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for loading SVG images via the `<img>` tag was not supported by openhtmltopdf until [this PR](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/pull/254) on July 16, 2018, which is referenced in the issue linked above.

Note that for the SVG renderer to be invoked, the URI must either end with the string "svg" or begin with the string "data:image/svg+xml;base64,".